# In ExtJS, what is dynamic() in SCSS?

Tags: extjs, sass

I am creating a SCSS for a component, and looking at ExtJS SCSS I find in Base.scss that a lot of variables (if not all) are defined as:

```
$form-field-empty-color: dynamic(gray);
$form-field-border-color: dynamic($neutral-color);
$form-field-border-width: dynamic(1px);
$form-field-border-style: dynamic(solid);
...
```

What is that `dynamic` function? My fu skill in search seems not to be the at the needed level :C

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ext uses Fashion, which is an extension of SASS. See: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/fashion.html

It's somewhat similar to `!default` in SASS, but it defers computation until all variables are known.